# Magento 2 - How to create FAQ page with accordion

Tags: magento2, cms, widget

I want to create a FAQ page with the Accordion widget (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html).

Is it possible to use it on a CMS page?

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: Here is the simple free module available for FAQ: https://marketplace.magento.com/prince-module-faq.html

Answer (score 22):

It is possible. If you want to use

```
data-mage-init
```

Then you do it like this:

```
<div id="element" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": false, "multipleCollapsible": true}}'>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <div data-role="trigger">
            <span>Title 1</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">Content 1</div>

    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <div data-role="trigger">
            <span>Title 2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">Content 2</div>

    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <div data-role="trigger">
            <span>Title 3</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is data-role

Comment: an attribute that is working with data-mage-init

Comment: read more about it here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html

Comment: This should be marked as the answer.

Comment: please be warned that data-mage-init gets garbled by wysiwyg edits - there is a need to immediately go in "source" mode, copy the line, then make sure you put it back after any wysiwyg

Answer (score 4):

This works for me :

```
<div data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": false, "multipleCollapsible": false}}'>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <div data-role="trigger">
            Title 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>
            Content 1 bla bla bla.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <div data-role="trigger">
            Title 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>
            Content 2 bla bla bla.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**I think you are having an issue with `data-mage-init` when saving or edit the content of the CMS page back.**
You can use accordion in CMS page by adding accordion js to your custom theme.
Add accordion js: `app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Theme_Name]/web/js/custom.js`

```
define([
"jquery",
"accordion",
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            "active": [1, 2],
            "collapsible": true,
            "openedState": "active",
            "multipleCollapsible": true
        });
    });
});
```

Add CMS page content:

```
<div id="accordion">
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <div data-role="trigger">
        <h4>Title 1</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div>

<div data-role="collapsible">
    <div data-role="trigger">
        <h4>Title 2</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="content"> It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>

<div data-role="collapsible">
    <div data-role="trigger">
        <h4>Title 3</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="content">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="element" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": false, "multipleCollapsible": true}}'>
<button class="accordion" data-role="collapsible">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel" data-role="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion" data-role="collapsible">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel" data-role="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion" data-role="collapsible">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel" data-role="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

```
.accordion {
background-color: #eee;
color: #444;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 18px;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
border: none;
outline: none;
transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
background-color: #ccc;
}

.panel {
padding: 0 18px;
background-color: white;
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="accordion" data-mage-init='{
    "accordion":{
        "active": [1, 2],
        "collapsible": true,
        "openedState": "active",
        "multipleCollapsible": true
    }}'>
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <div data-role="trigger">
        <h4>Title 1</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</div>

<div data-role="collapsible">
    <div data-role="trigger">
        <h4>Title 2</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="content"> It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>

<div data-role="collapsible">
    <div data-role="trigger">
        <h4>Title 3</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="content">Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.</div>
```